# Why am I getting the wrong URL?

Tags: magento-enterprise, template, url, enterprise-1.14

I am getting the wrong URL in an admin template. The URL should be the same URL that the user is on, but with parameters added. Why is the code returning what seems like the base URL? How do I retrieve the proper URL?

Current page URL example:
    https://admin.example.com/index.php/admin/admin/ggproduct/index/key/1234567891011abcdefg/?store=2

```
function switchStore(obj) {
  var storeParam = obj.value ? '?store=' + obj.value : '';
  setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/*') ?>' + storeParam); // Wrong URL
  return true;
}
```

Code rendered in the JavaScript code:

```
function switchStore(obj) {
  var storeParam = obj.value ? '?store=' + obj.value : '';
  setLocation('https://www.example.com/en-US/admin/ggcategory/index/key/1234567891011abcdefg/' + storeParam);
  return true;
}
```

Expected code (with correct URL):

```
function switchStore(obj) {
  var storeParam = obj.value ? '?store=' + obj.value : '';
  setLocation('https://admin.example.com/en-US/admin/ggcategory/index/key/1234567891011abcdefg/' + storeParam);
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because Magento uses the `secure_url` you defined in your configuration (`System > Configuration > General > Web`). It uses both for backend and secure areas (like customer area).

Even if you are on a different domain it simpy replace with the one you set.

If you do not want this behaviour just try setting `System > Configuration > General > Web > URL Options > Auto-redirect to Base` URL to "no".

Comment: Will that fix my issue of getting the wrong admin URL that the user is currently at? It doesn't seem to be about Auto-redirects, but rather an issue with `$this->getUrl()` when the `Custom Admin URL` setting is used.

Comment: BTW, changing the option did not work. The URL still renders `setLocation('https://www.example.com/...` instead of what I want `setLocation('https://admin.example.com/`